# HTML/PHP --> parameter via url (GET) --> How to encode with less effort

Tags: php, mysql, url, get

I've written a PHP/Mysql application for project management.
Unfortunately (because of my programmer-beginner-state) all buttons, which are used to open a input form (for editing several data) are sending parameters via URL.

E.g. if the user presses the button "EDIT PROJECT" the link `edit_project.php?project_id=12345&mode=edit` is called.
Which means the `edit_project.php` page receives it's parameters via `$_GET`.

If it would be only this single page and this single button it would be little effort to change the scripts.

But i have hundreds of buttons and many pages which are communication this dirty GET-way.

The problem: If i don't change the scripts, the user can manipulate the URL parameters manually.

So here's my question:
Does anybody have a trick / tip how to solve my problem with as less effort as possible? Is there a way to generally restrict URL param manipulation?

Comment: Unfortunately, hard lessons rarely have easy solutions.It will probably take less time to work through all of the files, and write them correctly and any "simple" solution, especially when you consider how much time you will spend fixing problems as they occur with the current code.

Comment: "If i don't change the scripts, the user can manipulate the URL Params manually." — The user can **always** manipulate whatever data their browser sends to your server manually.

Answer (score 0):

We cant stop the user from manipulating the URL.

However, you can check if the `project_id` belongs to the user and take actions accordingly.

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE project_id='123'AND user_id='5'");
if(!$query){ 
  // if project is not found with project_id=123 and user_id=5
  // Redirect to a 404 page or something
  header("Location: 404.php");
  // if project belongs to the user and a record is found, script will continue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can't prevent the user from sending you any GET or POST they like.**

Anything that user sends you should be validated server-side anyway.
Especially in a scenario where you deal with user-privileges and rights.

*Did user actually sent a number? Does he have the required rights to edit that? -etc.*

It should really be a case of users rather using buttons because it's easier than learning the link parameters and possible combinations.

If they have all the rights and prefer editing URL over clicking a button - why not let them?